# How to add button to user profile page in drupal

Tags: hooks, views, users

I start using drupal(7) 3 days ago and I have small task :

I'm using Profile2 Module to create 2 type of users (candite/employer) and I Want to create a button in the wiew page of the profile of employer.
[image]

I create new module for that to test if is an employer profil :

```
function ab_candidate_app_profile2_view_alter($build) {

  $test = $build['field_company_name']['#object'];
  if(isset($build))
    if($test->type == 'employer_'){

    // add the button here
    }


}
```

Thank you for your help

EDIT : and whene i do var_dump($build) i get next result :

```
 array (size=12)
  '#view_mode' => string 'account' (length=7)
  'field_company_name' => 
    array (size=16)
      '#theme' => string 'field' (length=5)
      '#weight' => int 0
      '#title' => string 'Name' (length=4)
      '#access' => boolean true
      '#label_display' => string 'above' (length=5)
      '#view_mode' => string 'account' (length=7)
      '#language' => string 'und' (length=3)
      '#field_name' => string 'field_company_name' (length=18)
      '#field_type' => string 'text' (length=4)
      '#field_translatable' => string '0' (length=1)
      '#entity_type' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
      '#bundle' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
      '#object' => 
        object(Profile)[56]
          public 'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
          public 'type' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
          public 'label' => string 'Employer ' (length=9)
          public 'uid' => string '10' (length=2)
          public 'created' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          public 'changed' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          protected 'entityType' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
          protected 'entityInfo' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          protected 'idKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'nameKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'statusKey' => string 'status' (length=6)
          protected 'defaultLabel' => boolean false
          public 'field_company_name' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_logo' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_company_description' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_country' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'rdf_mapping' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'entity_view_prepared' => boolean true
      '#items' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      '#formatter' => string 'text_default' (length=12)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '#markup' => string 'adel' (length=4)
  'field_logo' => 
    array (size=16)
      '#theme' => string 'field' (length=5)
      '#weight' => int 2
      '#title' => string 'Logo' (length=4)
      '#access' => boolean true
      '#label_display' => string 'above' (length=5)
      '#view_mode' => string 'account' (length=7)
      '#language' => string 'und' (length=3)
      '#field_name' => string 'field_logo' (length=10)
      '#field_type' => string 'image' (length=5)
      '#field_translatable' => string '0' (length=1)
      '#entity_type' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
      '#bundle' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
      '#object' => 
        object(Profile)[56]
          public 'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
          public 'type' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
          public 'label' => string 'Employer ' (length=9)
          public 'uid' => string '10' (length=2)
          public 'created' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          public 'changed' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          protected 'entityType' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
          protected 'entityInfo' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          protected 'idKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'nameKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'statusKey' => string 'status' (length=6)
          protected 'defaultLabel' => boolean false
          public 'field_company_name' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_logo' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_company_description' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_country' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'rdf_mapping' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'entity_view_prepared' => boolean true
      '#items' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=13)
              ...
      '#formatter' => string 'image' (length=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          '#theme' => string 'image_formatter' (length=15)
          '#item' => 
            array (size=13)
              ...
          '#image_style' => string '' (length=0)
          '#path' => string '' (length=0)
  'field_company_description' => 
    array (size=16)
      '#theme' => string 'field' (length=5)
      '#weight' => int 3
      '#title' => string 'Description' (length=11)
      '#access' => boolean true
      '#label_display' => string 'above' (length=5)
      '#view_mode' => string 'account' (length=7)
      '#language' => string 'und' (length=3)
      '#field_name' => string 'field_company_description' (length=25)
      '#field_type' => string 'text_long' (length=9)
      '#field_translatable' => string '0' (length=1)
      '#entity_type' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
      '#bundle' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
      '#object' => 
        object(Profile)[56]
          public 'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
          public 'type' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
          public 'label' => string 'Employer ' (length=9)
          public 'uid' => string '10' (length=2)
          public 'created' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          public 'changed' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          protected 'entityType' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
          protected 'entityInfo' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          protected 'idKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'nameKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'statusKey' => string 'status' (length=6)
          protected 'defaultLabel' => boolean false
          public 'field_company_name' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_logo' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_company_description' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_country' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'rdf_mapping' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'entity_view_prepared' => boolean true
      '#items' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      '#formatter' => string 'text_default' (length=12)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '#markup' => string 'teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest' (length=23)
  'field_country' => 
    array (size=16)
      '#theme' => string 'field' (length=5)
      '#weight' => int 4
      '#title' => string 'Country' (length=7)
      '#access' => boolean true
      '#label_display' => string 'above' (length=5)
      '#view_mode' => string 'account' (length=7)
      '#language' => string 'und' (length=3)
      '#field_name' => string 'field_country' (length=13)
      '#field_type' => string 'list_text' (length=9)
      '#field_translatable' => string '0' (length=1)
      '#entity_type' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
      '#bundle' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
      '#object' => 
        object(Profile)[56]
          public 'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
          public 'type' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
          public 'label' => string 'Employer ' (length=9)
          public 'uid' => string '10' (length=2)
          public 'created' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          public 'changed' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          protected 'entityType' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
          protected 'entityInfo' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          protected 'idKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'nameKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'statusKey' => string 'status' (length=6)
          protected 'defaultLabel' => boolean false
          public 'field_company_name' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_logo' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_company_description' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_country' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'rdf_mapping' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'entity_view_prepared' => boolean true
      '#items' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      '#formatter' => string 'list_default' (length=12)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '#markup' => string 'Malaysia (MY)' (length=13)
  '#pre_render' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '_field_extra_fields_pre_render' (length=30)
  '#entity_type' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
  '#bundle' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
  '#theme' => string 'entity' (length=6)
  '#entity' => 
    object(Profile)[56]
      public 'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'type' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
      public 'label' => string 'Employer ' (length=9)
      public 'uid' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'created' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
      public 'changed' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
      protected 'entityType' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
      protected 'entityInfo' => 
        array (size=22)
          'label' => string 'Profile' (length=7)
          'plural label' => string 'Profiles' (length=8)
          'description' => string 'Profile2 user profiles.' (length=23)
          'entity class' => string 'Profile' (length=7)
          'controller class' => string 'EntityAPIController' (length=19)
          'base table' => string 'profile' (length=7)
          'fieldable' => boolean true
          'view modes' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'entity keys' => 
            array (size=4)
              ...
          'bundles' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'bundle keys' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'label callback' => string 'entity_class_label' (length=18)
          'uri callback' => string 'entity_class_uri' (length=16)
          'access callback' => string 'profile2_access' (length=15)
          'module' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
          'metadata controller class' => string 'Profile2MetadataController' (length=26)
          'static cache' => boolean true
          'field cache' => boolean true
          'load hook' => string 'profile2_load' (length=13)
          'translation' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'schema_fields_sql' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'configuration' => boolean false
      protected 'idKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
      protected 'nameKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
      protected 'statusKey' => string 'status' (length=6)
      protected 'defaultLabel' => boolean false
      public 'field_company_name' => 
        array (size=1)
          'und' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      public 'field_logo' => 
        array (size=1)
          'und' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      public 'field_company_description' => 
        array (size=1)
          'und' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      public 'field_country' => 
        array (size=1)
          'und' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      public 'rdf_mapping' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'entity_view_prepared' => boolean true
  '#language' => string 'en' (length=2)
  '#page' => null
```

Comment: First, do it have to be a button? Maybe link would be enough? It can *look like* a button, with CSS, after all. Second, have you tried with devel module and `kpr()`? Or even with usual `var_dump()`? Inpsecting what really is in your `$build` may help. Try and share, please.

Comment: yes a link or button its ok for me , and yes i tried var_dump i will share my result thank you for your help

Comment: @Mołot Please Find the result in the edit of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve by overrieding the user-profile.tpl.php with this code :

```
<?php print render($user_profile); 

  if(isset($user_profile['profile_employer_'])){
  $account_info=menu_get_object('user');
  $acount_id = $account_info->uid;

 // var_dump($account_info);die();

  echo '<a href="/jobPortal/Apply/'.$acount_id.'">Apply Now</a>';
  }
  ?>
```

I overied this file in the next path :

C:\wamp\www\jobPortal\themes\bartik\templates\

Answer (score 0):

Your `$build` is an array, so it should be enough to add "fake" field to it:

```
$build['field_mymodule_button'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'link',
  '#text' => 'Click Here',
  '#path' => $path,
  '#weight' => 10,
  '#options' => array(
    'attributes' => array('class' => array('pretend-im-button-class'), 'id' => 'cool-id'),
      //REQUIRED?:
      'html' => FALSE,
   ),
);
```

Code sample from [here](https://api.drupal.org/comment/12939#comment-12939). Note that `'html' => FALSE` is reported as needed by some, and as not needed by others. Just see if you need it.

To control order of your rendered elements, use `'#weight'`. It's an int, so you may need to alter other elements to make a place for yours.